# Hibernate @UniqueConstraint Purpose

Tags: java, database, hibernate, annotations

Could you please clarify the actual purpose of this annotation?
  - What happens if we don't have corresponding constraint defined using SQL Table definition in DB. Will hibernate check for uniqueness when we try to do inserts? Or Is this the purpose of DB? If hibernate will not check while inserting what is the reason behind specifying this exclusively? If we are not auto-generating the Table definitions from Model classes, then is there any purpose for these annotations?

Comment: I don't think hibernate will check for uniqueness during inserts. It's the duty of the underlying database. May be it's used only for auto-generation of tables. Why don't you write a test and see what happens?

Comment: I have written the test and observed that Hibernate is not checking for uniqueness. I was curious to know why Hibernate will not check by sending a select query before insert and see whether data complies with specified constraints like this.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html):

> Specifies that a unique constraint is to be included in the generated
>   DDL for a primary or secondary table.

the provided constraint will be included in the generated DDL (meaning it will be used by schema generation tools).

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify the actual purpose of this annotation?
@UniqueConstraint attribute are instructions for schema generation tool to generate the corresponsing constraints.

What happens if we don't have corresponding constraint defined using SQL Table definition in DB. Will hibernate check for uniqueness when we try to do inserts?
No, Hibernate won't check for uniqueness.

Or Is this the purpose of DB?
Yes, this purpose is served with the help of DB.

If hibernate will not check while inserting what is the reason behind specifying this exclusively? 
For schema generation tool only

If we are not auto-generating the Table definitions from Model classes, then is there any purpose for these annotations?
Apart from generation schema, it provides readability about the uniqueness.